# Listview not selecting the default value

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a **ListView** which I put in the `WhereParameters` of a `LinqDataSource` but the `selected="True"` is not reflecting from the extract.

Here is the code:

```
 <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" ContextTypeName="AptDataContext" 
      EnableDelete="True" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" EntityTypeName="" 
      TableName="Apointement" 
      Where="@IsAvailable = True && @dateApt >= DateTime.Now"> 

      <WhereParameters>
         <asp:ControlParameter 
              Name="doctorName" 
              ControlID="DropDownList1" 
              PropertyName="SelectedValue"
              Type="String" />
      </WhereParameters>
 </asp:LinqDataSource>

 <div class="center">
   <asp:Label ID="lblChoseDoctor" runat="server" Text="Choose a Doctor Name"> </asp:Label>

   <div class="value-right"> 
     <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="180px" AutoPostBack="true" 
         OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" >
         <asp:ListItem selected="True" Text="DoctorA" Value="DoctorA" />  <=== should select 
         <asp:ListItem Text="DoctorB" Value="DoctorB" />                       doctor A 
         <asp:ListItem Text="DoctorC" Value="DoctorC" />

     </asp:DropDownList> 
   </div>  
 </div>
```

When I execute this it selected all the doctor. It should only select `DoctorA` and the `IsAvailable >= today date`.  This is not working since I added the `Where="@IsAvailable = True && @dateApt >= DateTime.Now` in the LinqDatasoure.

I tried also to put

```
   DefaultValue="DoctorA" 
<asp:ControlParameter
```

but it didn't work also.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the code of your DropDownList selected index changed method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are defining two parameters in your `Where` property, but I think you mean to just reference the columns.  Drop the "@" on the column names, and it should work:

```
Where="IsAvailable = True && dateApt >= DateTime.Now"
```

Comment: I changed it to  Where="IsAvailable = True && dateApt >= DateTime.Now">    but it didn't change anything.   It should only select DoctorA which is the default but it return all the Dortor A, B, C

Comment: @user3127986 Why aren't you using the WhereParameter you have setup in your WHERE clause? Like this: `Where="IsAvailable = True && dateApt >= DateTime.Now && DoctorName = @doctorName` Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: I tried this but didn't work...    Where="IsAvailable = True && dateApt >= DateTime.Now && DoctorName = DoctorA"    I got this error No property or field 'DoctorA' exists in type 'Apointement'  I guess I am missing some quotes but i can find the proper solution

Comment: @user3127986 Haha, we are getting closer. How about this? `Where='IsAvailable = True && dateApt >= DateTime.Now && DoctorName = "@doctorName"'` (according to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasource.where(v=vs.110).aspx), you have to wrap string comparisons in double quotes).  Notice that I changed the outer quotes to single quotes.

Comment: you cannot add " because it will close the first quotation.

Answer (score 0):

the solution was provided by jadarnel27 work !!!

I just added in the where clause of the LinqDatasource the following:

Where="IsAvailable = True && dateEssai >= DateTime.Now && doctorName = @doctorName">

Thanks for your excellent solution.